# Ajax JSON for each

Tags: jquery, ajax, for-loop, each

Hello guys i  had a simple ajax request this also is working fine, but i had to loop trought the data and display all 10 names in the object allready searched it in stack but the object which i had is a bit to complicated. any suggestions how i can solve it?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
   url: 'XXXXXXX',
   data: {
      format: 'json'
   },
   error: function() {
   alert('ERROR');
   },
   sasdataType: 'json',
   success: function(data) {
    /*var $hotelname = $('<h1>').text(data.result.hotel[0].displayname);
        $('#hotel-name').append($hotelname)*/
    console.log(data);
   },
   type: 'GET'
});
});
```

Comment: what is the structure of your `data`?

Comment: `data.result.hotel.forEach(function(h){console.log(h.displayname)}); ?!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'XXX',
    data: {
      format: 'json'
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('ERROR');
    },
    sasdataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data.result.hotel, function(index, value) {
        $('#hotel-name').append($('<h1>').text(value.displayname));
      });
    },
    type: 'GET'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='hotel-name'></div>
```

You cane directly loop through hotel to get the hotel names as below using `$.each`

```
$.each(data.result.hotel, function(index, value) {
  console.log(value.displayname);
});
```

Comment: yeah thanks this works fine and at least can u maybe tell me how i can bind the result on each h1  like this :     var $hotelname = $('<h1>').text(data.result.hotel[0].displayname);
        $('#hotel-name').append($hotelname) so at leas i have 10 h1 tags with name

Comment: Just use `value.displayname` here in case of `data.result.hotel[0].displayname`

Comment: @mY777 :  I see you have have accepted other answer even when it was answered after mine and also i have updated to `<h1>` tag as you asked. can i know the reason?

Comment: updated , for no reason i would like to accept all of them but yeah ur support was the most effecient thanks again :)

Answer (score 4):

hope this is helpful for you

```js
$.ajax({
   url: 'https://www.hrs.de/hotel/service/mmsuggest-group?query=k%C3%B6ln&language=de',
   data: {
      format: 'json'
   },
   error: function() {
   alert('ERROR');
   },
   sasdataType: 'json',
   success: function(data) {
    /*var $hotelname = $('<h1>').text(data.result.hotel[0].displayname);
        $('#hotel-name').append($hotelname)*/
    console.log(data);
  console.log(data.result);
data.result.hotel.forEach(function(hd){console.log(hd.displayname)});
   },
   type: 'GET'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I figured the structure OK, it should be something like:

```
$.each(data.result.district, function(index, district) {
     $.each($(district), function(index, hotel) {
         console.log($(hotel).displayname);
     });
});
```